# Redirect to URL in ASP CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have problem with redirect to another controler and action in application.

My Redirect Action look like:

```
    public IActionResult Redirect(NotificationItemViewModel model)
    {
        NotificationItemToggleReadCommand command = new NotificationItemToggleReadCommand();
        command.Id = new EntityId(model.Id);
        command.MarkAsRead = true;


        var result = CommandProcessor.Run(command);
        RedirectResult redirectResult = new RedirectResult(model.Subject.Url,true);
        return redirectResult;
    }
```

My model.Subject.Url is for example in this format : `Identity/User#/Details/b868b08c-b3ba-4f45-a7b6-deb02440d42f`

It's area/controller/action/id.
Problem is that my RedirectResult redirect me to:

```
notifications/Identity/User#/Details/b868b08c-b3ba-4f45-a7b6-deb02440d42f
```

and that route doesn't exist (controller/area/controller/action/id)
How can force this redirect to cut off the first this controller name?

My routes:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "controllerActionRoute",
                template: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                constraints: null,
                dataTokens: new { NameSpace = "default" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: For redirect to external URL this answer help you [redirect in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436052/7487135)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly then it is because you are on Notification area ( Some other area) and try to move out of that area.

For that you can do either of following thing.

1. Instead of providing relative url , please provide absolute url in RedirectResult. Right now problem is that when application fire redirect it consider relative url and that is problem.
2. Second solution is to use RedirectToActionResult instead of RedirectResult.

   ```
    RedirectToActionResult redirectResult = new RedirectToActionResult("Details", "User", new { @area = "Identity", @Id = "b868b08c-b3ba-4f45-a7b6-deb02440d42f" });
    return redirectResult;
   ```

In above I assume that area name is "Identity" and Controller name is "User" and action is "Details". Acition has one parameter that is with name "Id". You can change as per your requirement. In this you don't have to construct absolute url.

**Update 1**

If I assume that you always have to do root and ignore "notifications" at begining.

Atleast you can provide Url like this.

```
~/Identity/User#/Details/b868b08c-b3ba-4f45-a7b6-deb02440d42f
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately i don't have Possibility to get a absoule url. I always get this relative one and this url can point to other action and controller so i can't use second solution.

Comment: Please see my update and also I don't understand "User#". That might create problem.

Comment: For redirect to external URL this answer help you [redirect in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436052/7487135)