# .Net Core Web API --Redirect to external url from Post Method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Please advice how to redirect to external url from Post method using .Net core webapi. RedirectPermanent is not working.

```
public class RegisterUserController : Controller
{

  public async Task<RedirectResult> Post([FromBody] user)
    {
      ---somecode
        string url = "http://www.gmail.com";
        return RedirectPermanent(url) ;//--is not working
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am redirecting to external url. But it’s not redirecting.

Comment: That really doesn't add anything. Since this is an API, I'm going to assume your connecting via a thin client (AJAX, HttpClient, Postman, etc.) In all of these cases, a redirect does not happen automatically. All a redirect is a *response* with a 301/302 status code and a `Location` header. Importantly, it is a full response still, and completes the request/response cycle. Something like a web browser, is programmed to automatically follow the URL in the `Location` header and issue a new GET request for that. However, a thin client will not. You would need to issue a new GET request yourself.

Comment: @ChrisPratt any clue how to handle that in Angular client? I expected the browser to automatically handle the redirect with status 301 and Location headers.

Answer (score 1):

For redirect to specific URL use the **RedirectResult** class:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] user)
{
     //...
     string url = "http://www.example.com";
     RedirectResult redirectResult = new RedirectResult(url, true);
     return redirectResult;
}
```

The second parameter indicates whether the redirection should be permanent or not.